# jqgrid excelExport how usage exportOptions?

Tags: jquery, excel, jqgrid, export

The documentation says:

```
jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('excelExport', { url: 'ExportExcel.php' });
```

Where can I find `exportOptions` describe and usage like

```
jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('excelExport', { url: 'ExportExcel.php' ; 
    exportOptions: { array...} });
```

or view sample of the usage of this `exportOptions`?

Answer (score 0):

in source jqgrid:

```
excelExport : function(o) {
        o = $.extend({
            exptype : "remote",
            url : null,
            oper: "oper",
            tag: "excel",
            exportOptions : {}
        }, o || {});
        return this.each(function(){
            if(!this.grid) { return;}
            var url;
            if(o.exptype == "remote") {
                var pdata = $.extend({},this.p.postData);
                pdata[o.oper] = o.tag;
                var params = jQuery.param(pdata);
                if(o.url.indexOf("?") != -1) { url = o.url+"&"+params; }
                else { url = o.url+"?"+params; }
                window.location = url;
            }
        });
```

but not apply "exportOptions" in result url. 
imho must been :

```
excelExport : function(o) {
        o = $.extend({
            exptype : "remote",
            url : null,
            oper: "oper",
            tag: "excel",
            exportOptions : {}
        }, o || {});
        return this.each(function(){
            if(!this.grid) { return;}
            var url;
            if(o.exptype == "remote") {
                var pdata = $.extend({},this.p.postData);
                pdata[o.oper] = o.tag;

                pdata['exportOptions'] = o.exportOptions;

                var params = jQuery.param(pdata);
                if(o.url.indexOf("?") != -1) { url = o.url+"&"+params; }
                else { url = o.url+"?"+params; }
                window.location = url;
            }
        });
```

or another usage of "exportOption" ?